# Considering a custom domain for this site? wpquestions.com is for sale

Tags: discussion, domain-name

There's a [post on WPCandy](http://wpcandy.com/reports/wpquestions-dot-com-is-for-sale) mentioning that http://wpquestions.com is for sale. Some comments there have compared it to this site, suggesting the possibility of some sort of partnership.

Would a partnership be a viable idea, or could the domain be acquired for a redirect - similar to http://nothingtoinstall.com, or even https://askubuntu.com/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, a few issues off the top of my head

1. We've strongly de-emphasized custom domain names, for reasons both technical (it makes unified logins *incredibly* difficult, and nobody knows these sites are part of a network when they all have different names) and practical (naming [is ridiculously difficult](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/), takes forever, and is kind of a distraction.)
2. The actual domain is a pay-for-service affair, which is.. kind of [antithetical to everything we stand for](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/06/the-vast-and-endless-sea.html). If we assumed the domain, it'd be like a staunch republican switching districts to a heavily democratic area. There *will* be confusion, and a lot of it, and perhaps even some brand poisoning by association.

I appreciate the heads up, but it feels like a bad fit... I'd be happy to entertain any evidence to the contrary.

Comment: Completely Agree. +1

Answer (score -1):

As this site is called WordPress Answers I know that wpanswers.com is not being use. (The site is run on WP>org and the only post is the default admin post!)

So I would say to use that.

Comment: I still like http://answers.wordpress.org ;) but that could only happen in the future when WP.SE's SEO pushes forth in Google page rankings.